# JSON file data encoding issue for Google Script parsing

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I have a problem than I parse data from the JSON file into the Google Spreadsheet.

[image: Screen example of the JSON data]

My Google Script:

```
function JSON_from_DRIVE() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("1qwM5W6717FI28fkvBo9FcuJnqaaYo24H").getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var file1 = Utilities.newBlob(file, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(file1);
  var dataRows = dataAll['Body'];
  var rowHeaders = Object.keys(dataRows[0]);
  var rows = [rowHeaders];
  for (var i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++) {
    var rowData = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < rowHeaders.length; j++) {
      rowData.push(dataRows[i][rowHeaders[j]]); 
    }
    rows.push(rowData);
  }

  sheet.getRange(1,1,rows.length,rows[0].length).setValues(rows); 

}
```

And after script running I have following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0

In the debug mode of the code, I see in the console how the script sees the data in the JSON file.

There are some encoding collisions:

[image: Encoding collisions]

What additional functions can be written in the script so that the JSON file is perceived and parsed correctly?

Comment: How about just `JSON.parse(file)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you will take the advice of @TheMaster to use `JSON.parse(file)` instead of `JSON.parse(file1)` the code should give you this:

| t | v |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:28.6737824Z | -0.0662994 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:28.7899119Z | -0.0662994 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:28.8964373Z | -0.0950012 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:29.0035742Z | -0.0950012 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:29.1184731Z | -0.0806427 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:29.225578Z | -0.0806427 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:29.3333506Z | -0.0950012 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:29.4412116Z | -0.0950012 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:29.5544312Z | -0.0950012 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:29.6617705Z | -0.0950012 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:29.7683411Z | -0.0950012 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:29.8819891Z | -0.0806427 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:29.9894917Z | -0.0806427 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:30.0958958Z | -0.0662994 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:30.2092453Z | -0.0662994 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:30.3162308Z | -0.0806427 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:30.4294831Z | -0.0806427 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:30.5368671Z | -0.0806427 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:30.64393Z | -0.0806427 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:30.7566749Z | -0.0662994 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:30.8645995Z | -0.0662994 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:30.972218Z | -0.0662994 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:31.0863973Z | -0.0662994 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:31.1936985Z | -0.0662994 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:31.3010083Z | -0.0662994 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:31.40885Z | -0.0662994 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:31.5231228Z | -0.0662994 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:31.6302419Z | -0.0662994 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:31.7379175Z | -0.0662994 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:31.8515735Z | -0.0662994 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:31.9583902Z | -0.0662994 |
| 2021-10-04T19:46:32.0649162Z | -0.0662994 |

It seems it works fine.

Comment: Here is that JSON. I ocred it since you didn't bother to provide it in proper format: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OtlonhjVKMtxah9eyTTl_ikjXd_GIIkb/view?usp=sharing